# mysterious exception in htaccess rewrites

Tags: .htaccess

My htaccess files contains only a few lines that firstly remove the www and then add ".php" to the slug to get the correct php file, so

```
www.kalicup.fr/seo
```

should rewrite to

```
kalicup.fr/seo
```

and then display the file seo.php (without the .php extension displaying in the url itself)

at the moment

```
kalicup.fr/seo
```

correctly displays seo.php without showing the file extension.
however, when I try

```
www.kalicup.fr/seo
```

it rewrites to

```
kalicup.fr/seo.php
```

adding the .php extension in the url

so there's abviously a problem in my htaccess but I can't see it !
here's my code

```
Options +FollowSymLinks
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

ErrorDocument 404 /404.php

# redirect the url with www to url without
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.(([a-z0-9_]+\.)?kalicup\.fr)$ [NC]
RewriteRule .? http://%1%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,L]

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.(([a-z0-9_]+\.)?kalicup\.co\.uk)$ [NC]
RewriteRule .? http://%1%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,L]

# add .php to urls
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}.php -f
RewriteRule ^(.*?)/?$ $1.php [L]
```

can anyone see the problem ?

Answer (score 1):

Use that in your `.htaccess`:

```
Options +FollowSymLinks -MultiViews
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

ErrorDocument 404 /404.php

# redirect the url with www to url without
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.(([a-z0-9_]+\.)?kalicup\.(?:fr|co\.uk))$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^ http://%1%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,L]

# add .php to urls
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}.php -f
RewriteRule ^(.*?)/?$ $1.php [L]
```

Only one test for .fr and .co.uk.

And -MultiViews: http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/en/mod/core.html#options

The effect of MultiViews is as follows: if the server receives a request for /some/dir/foo, if /some/dir has MultiViews enabled, and /some/dir/foo does not exist, then the server reads the directory looking for files named foo.*, and effectively fakes up a type map which names all those files, assigning them the same media types and content-encodings it would have if the client had asked for one of them by name. It then chooses the best match to the client's requirements.
http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/en/content-negotiation.html

Comment: genius ! that works perfectly. I'd never even heard of Multiviews !!
Thanks

Comment: Well explained `MultiViews` +1

Comment: Glad to know it worked out, you may mark the answer as accepted by clicking on check mark on top-left of my answer. Thank you (and @anubhava thank you too!)